# I'm running a two sample t-test, is this the correct formula?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I am running a t-test to evaluate Conversion rates from website A vs website B.

My test is

```
var = ((Xa_clicks-1.0)*Xa_var + (Xb_clicks-1.0)*Xb_var)/(Xa_clicks+Xb_clicks-2.0)

sp = sqrt(var*(1/Xa_clicks + 1/Xb_clicks))

t_val = (CRa -CRb)/sp
```

Thanks!

Comment: What you seem to be doing doesn't make sense to me. Why are you comparing proportions for one subgroup with the combined data for both groups in the numerator but using a denominator for a subgroup-vs-subgroup comparison?

Comment: hmm. I must be confused. Should my t-test be `ttest= (CRa-CRb)/sp` Where sq is the sqrt of `((Xa_clicks-1.0)*Xa_var + (Xb_clicks-1.0)*Xb_var)/(Xa_clicks+Xb_clicks-2.0)`?   If I understand this correctly I am pooling the variance and testing sample A vs B.

Comment: Well, if I am reading it right that should (at least sort of) work, though strictly speaking it doesn't have a t-distribution. If you're asking a new question now you should probably edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have computed the standard two-sample t-statistic.

I have assumed of course that `CRa` and `CRb` are the group means, `Xa_var` and `Xb_var` are the group variances, and `Xa_clicks` and `Xb_clicks` are the two sample sizes, even though you chose to keep an air of mystery about these quantities in your post.